# Failed to run apache ignite after upgrading ubuntu to 19.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, ignite

I'm very new to apache ignite and trying to explore it to see if it is feasible to use it as in memory data grid.

I setup apache ignite on ubuntu 64 bit (v 18.04) and installed the debian package as per the instructions on ignite's website. so it ran fine. Later I got the notification to upgrade ubuntu to 19.04 which I did. after than whenever I try to run ignite:

```
 bin/ignite.sh config/default-config.xml
```

I get this error.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/usr/lib/apache-ignite/ignite-core-2.7.6.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Cannot write to work directory: /usr/share/apache-ignite/work
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1029)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:351)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot write to work directory: /usr/share/apache-ignite/work
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.workDirectory(IgniteUtils.java:9393)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:2178)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1756)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:962)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
    ... 1 more
Failed to start grid: Cannot write to work directory: /usr/share/apache-ignite/work
```

please bear in mind I'm not an expert user of linux and this is the first time I'm using ignite so is there anything that's missing?

Answer (score 3):

What configuration are you using?

With packaged Ignite, you should use a configuration which would set ignite work dir to `/var/lib/apache-ignite`.

You should be starting packaged Apache Ignite with command akin to

```
sudo service apache-ignite@default-config.xml start
```

and not from your user.

Comment: this I believe is the correct way to run it as demon service but when I execute this, sudo confirms my password and then. well nothing happens as **ps -ax | grep ignite** shows nothing except for grep itself. However if I precede my command with sudo it runs and then I have to do **^Z bg**, **disown**.  Where do you think the problem could be.

Comment: It's hard to say, it works for me without disown from root. What's it waiting on when started with sudo?

Comment: i dunno. would last few lines of log would give any idea?

Comment: Why not post the whole log on pastebin?

Comment: Do you have that on your console? That's strange. It starts in background for me.

Comment: yes. always and stucks on the last line as if it's waiting for something to happen

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that user which tries to start ignite doesn't have write permission for the work directory. Just set up correct permissions and all should be fine. You can refer any chmod guide such as https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-command-chmod-2201064 to check how this can be done.